# Pin tool,the static ins address (INS_Address(ins)) is different from the address of the instrumented instruction(IARG_INST_PTR)

Tags: assembly, x86, intel-pin

I want to print every rtn name, and instructions belong to this rtn. My code looks like this:
'''

```
for (SEC sec = IMG_SecHead(img); SEC_Valid(sec); sec = SEC_Next(sec))
{ 
    //OutFile << "SEC name: " << SEC_Name(sec) << endl;
    for (RTN rtn = SEC_RtnHead(sec); RTN_Valid(rtn); rtn = RTN_Next(rtn))
    {
        if(RTN_NumIns(rtn) >= 1){
            OutFile << RTN_Name(rtn) << ";" << std::dec << RTN_NumIns(rtn) << endl;

            RTN_Open(rtn);

            for (INS ins = RTN_InsHead(rtn); INS_Valid(ins); ins = INS_Next(ins))
            {
                OutFile << hex << INS_Address(ins) << ";" << INS_Disassemble(ins) << ";" \
                ...;
            }
            // to preserve space, release data associated with RTN after we have processed it
            RTN_Close(rtn);
        }     
    }
}
```

'''
then i ues INS_AddInstrumentFunction to print memery trace.
'''

```
VOID RecordMemRead(VOID * ip, VOID * addr)
{
    fprintf(trace,"%p: R %p\n", ip, addr);
}
VOID RecordMemWrite(VOID * ip, VOID * addr)
{
    fprintf(trace,"%p: W %p\n", ip, addr);
}

VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)
{
    UINT32 memOperands = INS_MemoryOperandCount(ins);

    for (UINT32 memOp = 0; memOp < memOperands; memOp++)
    {
        if (INS_MemoryOperandIsRead(ins, memOp))
        {
            INS_InsertPredicatedCall(
                ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)RecordMemRead,
                IARG_INST_PTR,
                IARG_MEMORYOP_EA, memOp,
                IARG_END);
        }
        if (INS_MemoryOperandIsWritten(ins, memOp))
        {
            INS_InsertPredicatedCall(
                ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)RecordMemWrite,
                IARG_INST_PTR,
                IARG_MEMORYOP_EA, memOp,
                IARG_END);
        }
    }
}
```

'''
finally, i got different ins address, Why is it happen? I've been stuck here too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INS_Address(ins) print address where an instruction is loaded during the **initial** **loading** of image. 
IARG_INST_PTR gives the address of the instruction when it is **executing**. Relocation of image happens at runtime. Hence addresses may be different.

see [instruction point value of dynamic linking and static linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62125651/instruction-point-value-of-dynamic-linking-and-static-linking). Your question is similar. just worded differently.