# instruction point value of dynamic linking and static linking

Tags: compilation, architecture, static-linking, dynamic-linking, intel-pin

By using Intel's pin, I printed out the instruction pointer (ip) values for a program with dynamic linking and static linking.

And I've found that their ip values are quite different, even though they are the same program.

A program with static linking shows  0x400f50 for its very first ip value.

but a program with dynamic linking shows 0x7f94f0762090 for its first ip value

I am not sure why they have that quite a large gap.

It would be appreciated if anyone could help me find out the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure why they have that quite a large gap.

Because a dynamically linked program does not start executing in the binary: the first few thousands of instructions are executed in the dynamic linker (`ld-linux`), before control is transferred to `_start` in the main executable.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61790355/50617).